# How to take n-th order discrete sum of numpy array (sum equivalent of numpy.diff)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I know that it is possible to take the n-th order discrete difference of a numpy array by using the numpy function `numpy.diff()`, but is there a way to do the same with the n-th order discrete sum?

Let's say we have a numpy array, `A = np.arange(10)`. The expected result for the 1st order discrete sum would be:

```
array([  1.,   3.,   5.,   7.,   9.,  11.,  13.,  15.,  17.])
```

which I can get from doing:

```
N = A.shape[0]
B = np.zeros(N-1)

for i in range(N-1):
    B[i] = A[i+1] + A[i]
```

But is there a function available to avoid having to use a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A[i+1]` for `for i in range(N-1)` would be covered by `A[1:]` and similarly `A[i]` for the same iteration means `A[:-1]`. So, basically you can sum these two versions of the input array to have a vectorized output in `B`, like so -

```
B = A[:-1] + A[1:]
```

Comment: It seems this method would also work with subtraction, so why does `diff` exist?

Comment: @Annan Probably because most users prefer a builtin in most scenarios. But a slicing based one would be more performant.